# Overlay an Iframe Button with another button that when pressed, the Iframe button will be pressed too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

;)
I have a page on my own website with an iFrame to another server.
There is a button in this iFrame but I don't like the style so im trying to cover with another my button.
So the question is: Its possible to cover the button in this iFrame with a my button and then, when my button pressed, the iFrame's button got pressed too? (so nobody see the ugly iFrame button but only mine but at same time, the iFrame's button do the action).
Hope you understand my point, if not I'll be glad to explain better :-)

Thanks in advance guys, wish you a great day ;-)

Kindly Regards,
G.C.

Comment: Hacking Issue? Why? Sorry we're a company, we don't do hacking...

Comment: Why dont you change the iframe source style ?

Comment: It sounds like they don't have access to the contents of the iframe.

Comment: Im sorry but you wrong. We have access to BUTTON in iFrame, but it's ugly (we are working under a boring client's request...) and we wanna cover with another one more beautiful...that's it! Sorry for mistake Max, we'll show the work if we can accomplish for remove all doubt :-) Thanks for your support Max, have a nice day :)

Comment: If you have access to the button, style it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of the iframe are on another server, you cannot access the contents of it.

Here's more information on that: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

#### Bad idea that might work, sort of

If you are able to position the button **exactly** over the one in the iframe, you may be able to pass through the user's click by applying `pointer-events:none` to your button.  That's going to be very tricky to pull off well, so I don't recommend you try it.  Don't try to trick your users.

Comment: Thanks!But my question is if is possible to make like a BUTTON on the SAME position of iFrame that when you click on it, you are thinking to click on it but the truth is that you are clicking on button back to this.So a sort of a button that doesen't exist but you can only see, you know what I mean? Example: MyPage => "CoverButton" => iFrame Rear the CoverButton so when i click on CoverButton in real im clicking on the iFrame button is just for cover the ugly button, I don't wanna access to iFrame button from my-side button :-) sorry I don't know how explain :) Thanks so much Chris!

Comment: Your site cannot access the contents of the iframe at all, so you can't pass on the fact that the user has clicked your button.  The only possible option is to use something like `pointer-events:none` on the button, but that really is a bad idea.

Comment: Hello Chris, Im searching about this function and Its exactly what im looking for!! I was looking on this page: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/ there is the example at bottom for selecting text but in real, I was selecting text under the cover so is EXACTLY what I've to do!!! THANK YOU now I do some test. But it works on iFrame? I didn knew this function, can you tell me an example if you wanna and you can? Thank you Chris!!! Thank you so much. For all other users, please no hacking here...we're just working under a client's request, I'm sorry for mistake.

Comment: Your Bad Idea WORKED LIKE A CHARM!!!!Thank you so much Chris, you solved our problems :-) I wish you a great day, thanks again for your support!! We'll show the end result for avoid any mistake ;-) Kindly Regards, G.C.

Comment: Make sure you very, very thoroughly test this in different browsers.  Even the slightest difference in rendering (on either your page or the one in your iframe) can ruin the illusion.  You're also not going to get very deep IE support.

Comment: Hello Chris, this is a web app for Mobile (both Android and iOS) but there is a small problem...I made a test on my local apache server and it works GREAT but when I put it on my server, the button got pressed but no actions done...Why? :( In my example when iframe's button pressed, it do an ECHO 'OK!'; so in local I see the echo but on my server the button got pressed but I can't see the "OK" echo...Any suggestion?